# Creating a Many-to-Many Relationship in Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

I have 2 entities in my database:
- STUDENT
- MODULE

This is a many-to-many relationship in that a STUDENT can take many modules and a particular MODULE can consist of many students.

How would I implement a many-to-many relationship using Nhibernate (only using .hbm files and NOT pure NHibernate) and how would the database and class structure look like

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial : http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/08/nhibernate-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: I don't find the above example very useful. Any other suggestions.

Comment: @user762342 Why isn't this useful? What's different in your case compared to the examples in the link?